# Send 2 files by email using a form HTML and PHP

Tags: php, html

Hi everybody I'm searching to solve a problem (looks easy but I don't find a solution).

I have a form HTML and I'm trying to send datas and files to a specific email.
The email arrives correctly but the 2 file attached have a strange name, it look like a temporary name file. It like I lost the name of the file and the extension.

Somebody could help me to understand what I'm doing wrong?
I'm not really an expert on PHP.

Thanks!

HTML file

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="email2.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<fieldset>
<legend>Canditatura</legend>
<label>Nome:</label> <input type="text" placeholder="Inserisci il tuo nome" name="nome"  size="30px" required="true"><br>
<label>Cognome:</label> <input type="text" placeholder="Inserisci il tuo cognome" name="cognome" size="30px" required="true"><br>
<label>Email:</label> <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="example@example.it" size="30px" required="true"><br>
<label>Telefono:</label> <input type="tel" name="telefono" placeholder="+39" size="30px"><br>
<label>Allegato 1:</label> <input type="file" id="allegato" name="allegato" required="true"><br>
<label>Allegato 2:</label> <input type="file" id="allegato2" name="allegato2" required="true"><br><br><br>
<label class="lprivacy"><input type="checkbox" required="true">Accetto normativa sulla Privacy</label><input type="submit" value="Invia Canditatura" name="submit">
</fieldset>
</form>
```

PHP File

```
    <?php
$allegato = $_FILES['allegato']['tmp_name'];
$allegato_type = $_FILES['allegato']['type'];
$allegato_name = $_FILES['allegato']['name'];

$allegato2 = $_FILES['allegato2']['tmp_name'];
$allegato2_type = $_FILES['allegato2']['type'];
$allegato2_name = $_FILES['allegato2']['name'];

$email = $_POST['email'];
$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$cognome = $_POST['cognome'];
$telefono = $_POST['telefono'];

  mail_attachment("test@test.com","Subject","Nuova canditatuda da <b>$nome $cognome</b>. <br> Telefono: $telefono <br> Email: $email ",array("$allegato","$allegato2"));
  function mail_attachment($to, $subject, $message, $files) {
      $headers = "From: no-reply@mail.com";
      $semi_rand = md5(time());
      $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";
      $headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" . "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" . " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";

      $message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" . "--{$mime_boundary}\n" . "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" . "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . $message . "\n\n";
      $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";

      foreach ($files as $file) {

        $filename = end(explode("/",$file));

        $data = file_get_contents($file);

        $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));

        $message .= "Content-Type: {\"application/octet-stream\"};\n" . " name=\"$file\"\n" .
          "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" . " filename=\"$file\"\n" .
          "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" . $data . "\n\n";
        $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";
      }
        echo (@mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) ? "<p>Messaggio spedito correttamente a $to!</p>" : "<p>ERRORE! Messaggio non spedito a $to!</p>";
  } // mail-attachment ?>
```

Comment: whats output names ?

Answer (score 0):

According to your code, your sending temp file but your not sending the original file name, so that's the received file name has some random file name.

**Check bellow code**

```
<?php    
$email = $_POST['email'];
$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$cognome = $_POST['cognome'];
$telefono = $_POST['telefono'];

  mail_attachment("test@test.com","Subject","Nuova canditatuda da <b>$nome $cognome</b>. <br> Telefono: $telefono <br> Email: $email ",array("allegato","allegato2"));
  function mail_attachment($to, $subject, $message, $files) {
      $headers = "From: no-reply@mail.com";
      $semi_rand = md5(time());
      $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";
      $headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" . "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" . " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";

      $message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" . "--{$mime_boundary}\n" . "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" . "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . $message . "\n\n";
      $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";

      foreach ($files as $f) {

        $file = $_FILES[$f]['tmp_name'];

        $filename = $_FILES[$f]['name'];;

        $data = file_get_contents($file);

        $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));

        $message .= "Content-Type: {\"application/octet-stream\"};\n" . " name=\"$file\"\n" .
          "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" . " filename=\"$file\"\n" .
          "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" . $data . "\n\n";
        $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";
      }
        echo (@mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) ? "<p>Messaggio spedito correttamente a $to!</p>" : "<p>ERRORE! Messaggio non spedito a $to!</p>";
  } // mail-attachment ?>
```

Instead of passing file uploaded paths, I passing HTML elements to the function, so that it will fetch necessary Information and attach file(s) and it will send mail.

Comment: Thanks Jitendra I understand but still have the same files named with the temp "code" ( /tmp/phpJih9x2 ). I don't know what try more. Looks realy easy to solve but nothing. Have another advice? Thanks

Comment: Ok I found the solution (of course thanks to you). In this part of the code (filename=\"$file\"\n" .) I changed with $filename. THANKS A LOT! It works

Comment: @Prova17 that's great, can you change status to solved.